# Смена иконки через javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть 2 иконки `play/pause`, при нажатии на `play` должна появляться `pause`, но в момент когда появляется `pause` иконка `play` не исчезает и получается наложение одной иконки на другую. Как это исправить?

```js
let playIcon = "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/149/149668.svg";
let pauseIcon = "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/149/149670.svg";

function togglePlay(video) {
  var audio = document.getElementsByTagName("audio")[0];
  if (!audio)
    return;
  audio.paused ? audio.play() : audio.pause();
  document.getElementById("button").src = audio.paused ? playIcon : pauseIcon;
}
```

```css
@media (max-width: 479px) {
   img {
      display: none; 
   } 
}   
#button {
  width: 50px;
  display: block; 
}
```

```html
<div class="player" onclick="togglePlay(this)">
  <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/149/149668.svg" id="button">
  <audio>
        <source src="https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/mp3/bachfugue.mp3" />
    </audio>
  </div>
```

[результат](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4T7Z.jpg)

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Не наблюдается ничего странного, приложите скрин

Comment: @StrangerintheQ я понял в чем проблема, только не знаю как исправить. Посмотрите вопрос еще раз пожалуйста. Я обновил

Comment: а на каком устройстве/браузере проблема?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ в мобильной версии всех устройств

Comment: картинку можно вставлять сразу из буфера обмена, поставьте курсор, в место вставки и нажмите ctrl+v, если у Вас windows

Comment: @StrangerintheQ хорошо. только все равно непонятно почему она не исчезает, а остается на месте. может добавить что-то чтобы исчезала сразу после нажатия

Comment: Приведенный сниппет на сафари работает без проблем

Comment: @StrangerintheQ тогда я вообще не понимаю в чем проблема(

Comment: вроде бы все норм работает

Comment: @StrangerintheQ у меня там `audio[0]` стоит, поэтому только для первого блока работает. А как для всех сделать?

Comment: @TigranVardanyan у меня там audio[0] стоит, поэтому только для первого блока работает. А как для всех сделать?

Comment: @AsasSas попробуйте png картинки.., это я про оригинальный вопрос

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, да не, все работает с этим. там в css ошибка была. теперь другой вопрос, последний:) помогите пожалуйста с ним

Comment: @AsasSas вы не правильно понимаете суть stackoverflow, это не сайт по бесплатной помощи для разработчиков по, это сайт вопросов и ответов по программированию, вы задаете следующий вопрос, позвольте всем другим участникам сообщества, возможно изущим ответ на аналогичный вопрос гайти Ваш, не задавайте новый вопрос в комментириях

Comment: @StrangerintheQ я все понимаю, и я очень благодарен Вам за помощь, но мне очень нужен ответ только на этот вопрос и все, честно

Comment: @AsasSas я отвечу Вам позже, ускакал от компа, сейчас могу лишь только сказать что надо искать следуюзий элемент в разметке, например